# Navigationbar not showing on pushing view controller

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, viewwillappear

I have working on navigation base application.
my problem is that when i am push other view controller into navigation controller .view controller viewWillAppear is not called.

`TestCategoryHistory *testVC = [[TestCategoryHistory alloc] initWithNibName:@"TestCategoryHistory" bundle:nil];`

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:testVC animated:YES];
[testVC release];`
```

here  test's viewWillAppear is not called.And also navigationbar is not showing..

Comment: Yes, it is called.But main Problem is that navigationbar is not showing in viewcontroller.

Comment: @AntonioMG viewWillLoad... are you sure?

Comment: My mistake . It is also not called on it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

make sure your current view controller is "in" a Navigation controller. Only so, you can push another view controller to show.

Comment: Yes my current view controller is navigation controller and viewdid load is called but problem is that navigation bar is not showing in view.

Comment: Did TestCategoryHistory view controller hide the bar? check whether  bar hidden setting. self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = YES;

Comment: self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = NO. on viewDidLoad method. But it's not working.

Comment: Check this line NSLog(@"Navigation Controller %@",self.navigationController);